# merge 'if out of range' and 'if item equals' in one condition

Tags: python

```
   if col-2 > 0:
       if matrix[row, col-2] != 0:
           col -= 2
           # some code here 1 
       else:
           # some code here 2
   else:
       # some code here 2
```

I have many pieces of code like this. Not exactly like this one, but many conditions in my code work the same way. I'd like to merge `if col-2 > 0:` and `if matrix[row, col-2] != 0:` to get rid of many duplicated lines all over the code (# some code here 2). The problem of merging is checking if an item is non-zero even if that item is out of range.

Comment: IMHO, how about just write `if col-2 > 0 && matrix[row, col-2] != 0: #branch1... else: #branch2...`?

Comment: You could put the condition in its own method so you could call something like `if outOfRange() and itemEquals(matrix[row,col-2], 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as simple as

```
if col-2 > 0 and matrix[row, col-2] != 0:
    # code 1
else: 
    # code 2
```

Note that `matrix[row, col-2] != 0` will not be executed if `col-2 > 0`is not true.

You can see this more clearly with something like:

```
def raiseError():
    raise ValueError()

if False and raiseError():
    print("Won't get here")
else:
    print("No error was raised")
```